# HashSet vs ArrayList contains() performance for several small String collections

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashset

This question is essentially an addendum to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32552307/4900327) which already asks about Java's `contains()` performance, but my use case targets collections with a small number of String elements.

To make the problem more precise, there will be:

- Only `java.lang.String` elements in the collection (thus using `String.equals(...)` in the `contains(...)` calls).
- String have average length of 16.
- The **average** number of elements in a single collection is 7.
- The collection will face frequent `contains(...)` checks, occasional additions, and no removals.
- Ordering of Strings is not important at all.
- This code would run on a web server, and there would be a large number of such collection objects (~1000 per user request).

Which collection would be a better fit for this use-case, both memory-wise and time-wise?

Comment: This is better answered by results of actual testing and benchmarking...

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to know if anyone has gone through this process before, and what their findings were.

Comment: For specific input constraints, you'll need to benchmark to be sure which one's faster. However, the post you linked to should already tells you that `contains` is O(1) vs O(n), which seems to answer the more general question. ArrayList generally uses marginally less memory than HashSet.

Comment: It is evident that using HashSet is faster (from that post). Regarding memory, I guess there shouldn't be a big difference (considering 7000 objects per request). Using a profiler will give you the memory it takes

Comment: @user7 Is it though? Remember, the use case calls for 1000 HashSets of size 7, not one of size 7000. In such a case, the cost of creating and managing the HashSet instances might outweigh the cost of `contains(...)` calls.

Comment: @Dukeling Big-O is only useful for considering large values of `n`, because it ignores constant overhead. Since `n` will only be 7, Big-O is useless for comparison, given that _O(1)_ may actually be slower than _O(n)_ for `n=7`. Actually, since `n` is known to be 7, _O(n)_ is actually _O(7)_, which means _O(1)_, so there is really no difference between _O(1)_ and _O(n)_

Comment: @Andreas exactly why I asked this question, thanks :)

I want to point out though, it is 7 _on average_. Won't be exactly 7.

Comment: @Dukeling I wouldn't call 5.5x "marginally less memory" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799668/4900327)

Comment: The difference may be there. We can't tell without profiling/benchmarking

Comment: @Dukeling I've mentioned this in both the question and these comments: I plan to create ~1000 collections per user request. A saving of 1 ms shaves off 1 entire second per user request.

Comment: If you're doing 1000 contains checks per request, that sounds like a design problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Which collection would be a better fit for this use-case, both memory-wise?

A `String[]`. Cannot be more compact than that.

Of course, that's not really a `Collection`, but I took that in the loosest meaning possible.

For best lookup (`contains`) performance, make it sorted and use binary search.

> ... and time-wise?

Probably a `HashSet`, but **you need to test performance** of such small collections, because the *O(log n)* performance of e.g. binary search may actually be faster than the *O(1)* performance of a hash table lookup, when `n` is only 7.

For that small a value of `n`, the performance difference may be negligible, and memory footprint may be more important.

Deciding between memory footprint and runtime performance, only **you** can decide which is "a better fit". We can't decide that for you.

Comment: `String[]` would not be a possibility, unfortunately. As mentioned, I do not know the number of elements beforehand to instantiate the array. 7 is just an average, in rare cases there might be as many as 20.

Comment: @abhidivekar You said *"occasional additions"*, so you resize array whenever you need to add another value, then do binary search to find where to add the value. Since it's only *occasional*, performance will not suffer, but then again, it depends on how often *occasional* occurs, and **only testing** will tell you that.

Comment: Hmm, yes that's true. And I will definitely test it before putting it into production, I'm just digging deeper into the problem at the moment :)