# Compare two list and output missing and extra element in Java

Tags: java, list, performance

I have two lists of strings List A and B.Lists might have same length or maybe one is longer than the other.There's no duplicate values in each list.They consist of random numbers.

What I want to do is to find the missing and the extra element exists in A compared to list B.And save them in two new lists , one for missing elements and one for extra elements.

For Example :

```
A = ["3000047" , "3000042" , "3000030"  , "30000475"]

B = ["3000047" , "3000043" , "3000030" ]
```

The output should be

```
Missing = ["3000043"]

Extra = ["3000042" , "30000475"]
```

I think of doing at as below. But not sure about the performance and its efficiency.

1. Read element from A.
2. Check if element exists in B.
3. If no add it to Extra list.
4. If yes remove the element from both A and B.
5. If B is empty add all renaming elements in Extra list.
6. If A is empty add all renaming elements in Missing list.

Answer (score 8):

> But not sure about the performance and its efficiency

Performance wise, use `Set` (`HashSet` implementation) instead of `List`. This will give better `O` time complexity at:

> 2. Check if element exists in B.

This is when you'll apply `contains` method. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552348/6908551) answer for details on that.

> Contains for a `HashSet` is `O(1)` compared to `O(n)` for a list, therefore you should never use a list if you often need to run `contains`.

---

The algorithm that you've proposed could be achieved using Java built-in functions.

#### [`Set#removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

```
Set<String> A = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("3000047", "3000042", "3000030", "30000475"));
Set<String> B = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("3000047", "3000043", "3000030"));

Set<String> copyA = new HashSet<>(A);
Set<String> copyB = new HashSet<>(B);

copyB.removeAll(A);
System.out.println("Missing: " + copyB);

copyA.removeAll(B);
System.out.println("Extra: " + copyA);
```

**Output**

```
Missing: [3000043]
Extra: [3000042, 30000475]
```